# How to jump to a specified tab in a multiple tab make with jquery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tabs

I'm sorry, i'm absolute newbie in jquery and tools...

I use multiple tabs in my page and i can not create link to open a tab if the link isn't in the wrap of tabs.

Here is my html code :

```
<a href="#tab2">AN EXTERNAL LINK TO TAB2</a>
<div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="current"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pane">content with <a href="#tab2">A INTERNAL LINK TO TAB 2</a></div>
        <div class="pane">content</div>
        <div class="pane">content</div>
    </div>   
</div>
<div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="current"><a href="#tab5">Tab4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5">Tab 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab6">Tab 6</a></li>
        </ul>
       <div class="pane">content</div>
        <div class="pane">content</div>
        <div class="pane">content</div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Is my script correct on the bottom of the body ?
The script :

```
<script>

    // perform JavaScript after the document is scriptable.
    $(function() {

        $("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane");
    });
</script>
```

What i'have missing ? I think it's possible with multiple tabs...

A big thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click event on the desired tab when the target link is clicked. In this case you'd want to assign class names to your tabs and links since they're a little faster than attribute selectors (such as `[href=#tab2]`).

So in your HTML:

```
<a href="#tab2" class="target-tab-2">AN EXTERNAL LINK TO TAB2</a>

...

<li><a href="#tab2" class="tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
```

JS:

```
$('.target-tab-2').click(function (e) { $('.tab-2').click(); e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, but it's dont work...the link show mydomain.com/mypage.html#tab2 but it don't open the tab...I have exactyly the same probleme to open in any tab an other tab if it's not in the same wrap. Are-you shure my  $("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane");
 script is correct ?Is a option needed to work with anchor in multiple pan ? Is a basehref problem (i use modx with a this <base href="[(site_url)][~[*id*]~]">. But i think that i correct....

Comment: No issue ? Perhaps a problem with the history option ? Mine is false.

Comment: The History option block all tabs after the first......Bullshit !

I have perhaps a solution :


For the internal links to tab : use direct href:#tab1


For the external link : use href:thepage.html#tab1

Comment: I'am sorry Derek...Your script work fine, but active all the tabs with the class .tab-2.

How to activate only the id #tab2 ?

Comment: You'd only give that tab the class of `tab-2`. You can change `$('.tab-2').click();` to `$('[href=#tab2]').click();` if you wanted to as well.

Comment: Than you very much Dereck ! It's work perfectly now ! But i have a lot of link like this one. Is possible to put directly your script in the link like <a href="your script here">go to #tab2</a>. I'm sorry..I'm a very big newbie....